# fundamental doubt in definition of routing table

Tags: distributed-systems, computer-networks

I have some very simple doubt in definition of routing table, and would be thankful if anybody could clarify it.

The doubt is that can the routing table of any node, say w, be smaller than the degree of w?

In other words, to route packet from w to its neighbour, say y, is it required that there should be some entry corresponding to y in the routing-table(w), or is it possible that the information(address) of y is contained in the header of the packet that arrived at node w?

Thanks.